# Route [/createhotel] not defined. laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, routes

This is my index view page.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="css/hotel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>

@section('content')
<h2>Hotels</h2>

<div class="container-fluid sug-1">
    <div class="ui_column is-12 h1 ui_header sug-1head">{{ $data[0]->city}}&nbsp;
    </div>
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">   

@for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)

  <div  class= "img__wrap">
  <form method="get" action="/hotel/viewpost.blade.php"> 
    <a href="/hotel/viewpost/{{$data[$i]->id }}"><img class = "img__img" src={{asset($data[$i]->image)}} alt="Logo" style="width:90%;height:90%" ></a>
    <p class = "img__description"> {{$data[$i]->name}} <br> {{$data[$i]->rating}}<br> {{$data[$i]->price}}</p>
  </form>
      </div>
@endfor

 <input class="sug1btn"  type=Button id="allsugbtn" onclick="findHotels();" value="See all"/>

</div>

@endsection

</body>
</html>
```

This is controller for my index:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HotelController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
        $hotelData['data'] = \DB::table('hotels')->get();
        if(count($hotelData) > 0)
        {
            return view("hotel.index",$hotelData);
        }
        else
        {
            return view("hotel.index");
        }
   } 


}
```

I created a route from my index to viewpost i.e. following code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <link href="css/hotel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>



</head>
<body>

@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid sug-1">
    <div class="ui_column is-12 h1 ui_header sug-1head">
    </div>
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: left; align-items: left">   

 <div class="card">
  <img src={{asset($data->image)}} alt="Image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>{{$data->name}}</b></h4> 
    <p>Rating: {{$data->rating}}<br>Price: {{$data->price}}</p> 
  </div>
</div>

 <button href="{{ route('/createhotel') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
</div>

<h2>Reviews</h2>

@foreach ($reviews as $review)
    <p>{{ $review->user_name }}<br>{{ $review->description }}</p>
    <br><br><br>

@endforeach

@endsection

</body>
</html>
```

This is HotelPostController for my viewpost and createhotel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HotelPostsController extends Controller
{
    public function show($hotelviewid)
   {
        $imagedata['data'] = \DB::table('hotels')->select('id','image','name','city','rating','price' )->where('id', $hotelviewid)->first();

        $reviewdata['reviews'] = \DB::table('hotel_reviews')->where('hotel_id', $hotelviewid)->get();


        return view("hotel.viewpost",$imagedata,$reviewdata);
   }

   public function createhotel()
   {
        return view("hotel.createhotel");
   }
}
```

This is web.php routes file:

```
Route::get('/', 'HotelController@index');
Route::get('/hotel', 'HotelController@index');
Route::get('/hotel/viewpost/{hotelviewid}', 'HotelPostsController@show');
Route::get('travelapp.me/hotel/viewpost/createhotel, 'HotelPostsController@createhotel');
```

The problem I am facing is that in views folder I have created a sub folder by name of hotel, it has 3 files index, viewpost and createhotel. the frst page is index and when a user clicks on some post it opens in viewpost. Now from there I want to create a button that goes to the third page i.e. creathotel. I have created a funtion in controller also added routes but it gives the error of undefined routes.

Comment: You have posted code of all those which are already working and does not have any problem but you did not posted code for `HotelReviewController`...and what is the link that you have written to open up the create page?

Comment: I have removed `HotelReviewController` part now the situation is that I am on viewpost page. then after clicking a button I want to go to createhotel page.

Comment: Okay now create a method called `create()` in your `HotelController` and create a route to point that method. and I assume that you dont wanna got to external route right (`'travelapp.me/hotel/viewpost/createhotel`)...what is this 'travelapp.me/hotel/viewpost/createhotel

Comment: remove `travelapp.me` if you wanna use `'HotelPostsController@createhotel'`, and just point your link to `/hotel/viewpost/createhotel`....see my post below

Comment: I thought I had to add the complete route so I added this.`travelapp.me/hotel/viewpost/createhotel`

Comment: see my post below buddy.

Comment: `/hotel/viewpost/createhotel.` I used this there is no error now but it just won't go to createhotel page

Comment: because your route you defined as `travelapp.me/hotel/viewpost/createhotel` see the asnwer post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Route::get('travelapp.me/hotel/viewpost/createhotel, 'HotelPostsController@createhotel');
```

to

```
Route::get('/hotel/viewpost/createhotel, 'HotelPostsController@createhotel');
```

And your button to go to create page:

```
<a href="{{url('/hotel/viewpost/createhotel')}}">Create Hotel</a>
```

The method `url()` will give you the full URL automatically. You just need to create URL from root (`/`) and you dont have to attache full domain.

You can do like this (Just an example)

```
Route::get('/hotel-create, 'HotelPostsController@createhotel');
```

and button to go to that page

```
 <a href="{{url('/hotel-create')}}">Create Hotel</a>
```

Now in this example, When you click on Create Hotel link, this will gonna call the method `createhotel()` of `HotelPostsController` controller.

**Update:**
**Problem**
In your controller you are not passing any data to the view

```
public function createhotel()
{
     return view("hotel.createhotel");
}
```

So how can you access the variable called $data on

```
<img src={{asset($data->image)}} alt="Image" style="width:100%">
```

**Solution: (Pass your data to template)**

```
public function createhotel()
{
    $imagedata['data'] = \DB::table('hotels')->select('id','image','name','city','rating','price' )->where('id', $hotelviewid)->first();

     $reviewdata['reviews'] = \DB::table('hotel_reviews')->where('hotel_id', $hotelviewid)->get();
     return view("hotel.createhotel",$imagedata,$reviewdata);
 }
```

Comment: It is now giving error `Trying to get property 'image' of non-object (View: \htdocs\travelapp\resources\views\hotel\viewpost.blade.php)`

Comment: Wht it is trying giving error for image that I used in viewpost. although the url changed to `http://travelapp.me/hotel/viewpost/createhotel`

Comment: yeah URL will be changed automatically, when you place your image on HTML file use fill path like `<img src="{{url('/img/img.1')}}">` or `<img src="{{asset('/img/img.1')}}">`

Comment: But I am getting image from db and accessing it thorugh php var

Comment: see the solution buddy

Comment: I have updated my post, please see the solution, actually the variable that you want to access on your view page is not passed from your controller, You have to pass data to your view page. See if that works

Comment: bud thank you very much it finally works thank you thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The `route()` helper method accepts the name as the parameter, not the actual route.

`route('create')` is what you want. To use the url, `url('/hotel/create')`.

Comment: can you please elaborate. I am a little confuse.

Comment: You have a button:

`<button href="{{ route('/createhotel') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>`

The route method you are using is expecting a named route. You are passing in the url of the route, not the name. Good news, you already have the name defined:

`Route::get('/hotel/create', 'HotelReviewController@create')->name('create');`

So use the name 'create' in the route. Or use a different method, `url('the/actual/route/here')`.

Comment: Ok i did it. the error is gone but it still won't go to the page. i.e. createhotel

Comment: `http://travelapp.me/hotel/viewpost/1` this is the link when I am on viewpost page. so in Route do I have to add hotel/viewpost/1/createhotel or not?

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself by having routes that are very similar. It's confusing me too. I told you about the named route that points to `HotelReviewController@create`, but I think you're wanting to hit `HotelPostsController@createhotel`. You would need to give this route a name and change what I told you to match that new name. Your names can be more clean too, like `hotel.create`. Also, this is a hotel post, so why is the method createHotel? I think just 'create' is fine. Then it could return a view `hotels.posts.create`, with that folder structure. Just my opinion there though.

Comment: `HotelReviewController@create` and `HotelPostsController@createhotel` they are meant for same page create = createhotel. my view page name in createhotel(for creating new post for hotel) I was trying things to make it work thats why code got a little messy. What I want to do is when I am on viewpost then after clicking the button I can go to create page page. `http://travelapp.me/hotel/viewpost/1` here 1 is parameter for viewpost page.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge of laravel or web. I just started on web course 10 days ago

Comment: You don't have to apologize- we're just offering help. :)

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't mean for this to hit the show method. Your createhotel method does not have an ID passed to it??

Change your route to:
`Route::get('/hotel/viewpost/{id}', 'HotelPostsController@show')->name('viewpost.show');`

Then your createhotel method in the controller has a parameter of $id passed to it that you can use. Return your view there. Then in the blade file:

`<button href="{{ route('viewpost.show', ['id' => 1]) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>`

Comment: thank you for your help the error is removed and now it navigates. I used a solution given by webDev. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/hotel/create', 'HotelReviewController@create')->name('create');
```

change it to

```
 Route::get('/hotel/create', 'HotelReviewController@create')->name('createhotel');
```

it will work i hope. you are using named route read here about routing.
   https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes

Answer (score -1):

in your index action value filled by a view blade page and it seems wrong

`<form method="get" action="/hotel/viewpost.blade.php">`

and in viewpost you need to change {{ route("/create") }} to {!! route("create")!!}